# Fetching data from list

Tags: java

I need to take the first 200 string from an List of Strings, I'm doing with a for loop(kid's stuff) with a flag inside. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Show us what you doing?

Comment: There exists a subList method which do what you want : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html. If you're not sure to have 200 elements, you can do `List<String> sl = list.subList(0, Math.min(200, list.size());`

Comment: Get the min of 200 and length of the list, then loop using that variable.

Answer (score 3):

Do it like this:

```
   List sublist = list.subList(0, 200);
```

If you have used generics, then remember to include them in the sublist:

```
  List<String> sublist = list.subList(0, 200);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain your `List` has more than `200` elements, you can use the 'subList' method.

**Example**

```
List<String> l = bigList.subList(0, 200);
```

If you're not sure if it does have 200, and you want to get as much as possible, in one line you can do something like:

```
List<String> l = bigList.size() >= 200? bigList.subList(0, 200):bigList.subList(0, bigList.size());
```

Comment: Chris if the list is shorter than 200 there is no need to sublist it, you could just use the whole bigList.

Comment: Or more simple, `List<String> l = bigList.subList(0, Math.min(200, bigList.size()));`

Comment: But if you don't know either way, then you can have something that will get both. I thought it would be nice to do it in one line. @ZouZou I do like your alternative!